# App Ownership Transfer - User's Perspective

Tags: android, download, apk, multiple-users

We have a app which is listed under a google account and the existing Google Account Holder is no longer supporting the app and wants us to take ownership.

They will fill the form to transfer the app to us.

We have a question, the current app is already downloaded by some users.

When this app is transferred and listed under our account will the users need to download the app again on their phone by un-installing the current app?

Please note there are no changes in the app we are just transferring the ownership and switching the google play account. Its a free app for users.

Wanted to know what is reflected on the user's end who are already using the app downloaded with previous ownership.

Are the user's required to re-download the app from play store after the completion of account transfer?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions; I'm not sure you'll find an answer here. Going through Play stores terms and conditions and then asking on reddit, quora, etc would probably be a better fit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: I don't this is offtopic because its a genuine query of a "programmer"

Answer (score 1):

Changing the owner does not affect end user and they would not be force to do anything - most likely they won't even notice the change. Please remember though, that you must obtain original signing key from the former owner, otherwise you will NOT be able to issue any updates to that app which would make the whole ownership transfer futile as you will be forced to submit app again (as like completely new app).